# Asking for user input during loading screen

Tags: python

```
import sys
import time

loading = True
loading_string = "." * 3
sys.stdout.write("Press Enter to Launch")
while loading:
    for index, char in enumerate(loading_string):
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.7)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    index += 1
    sys.stdout.write("\b" * index + " " * index + "\b" * index)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I'm making an interface in cmd that asks for a user input while giving them a ". . ." loading screen. It prints out "Press Enter to Launch", then 3 consecutive dots printed in a short delay, then resets to "Press Enter to Launch" with no dots and then repeats.

The problem is, the input() function in Python 3 stops all code until the user presses a key, in this case, Enter.

I was wondering if it was possible to run the code that simulates the ". . ." loading screen, while asking for a user input.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to accomplish here. Do you mean one portion of the screen should show some sort of ASCII animation while the user is able to input something in another? Try `curses` or some wrapper library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the threading module to run code while asking for user input.